# Is it possible to skip the processing of one column?

Tags: featuretools

I want to keep one column of my dataframe in its original state, not applying any primitive to it, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `ignore_variables` parameter to `ft.dfs`. Here's an example on a demo entity set.

```
import featuretools as ft
es = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)
es.plot()
```

[image: example entity set]

if we want to build features for the sessions entity, but ignore the `device` variable, we can run

```
feature_defs = ft.dfs(target_entity="sessions",
                      entityset=es, 
                      agg_primitives=["count", "mode"],
                      trans_primitives=[],
                      ignore_variables={"sessions": ["device"]},
                      features_only=True)
```

`feature_defs` has the following features

```
[<Feature: customer_id>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: MODE(transactions.product_id)>,
 <Feature: customers.zip_code>,
 <Feature: MODE(transactions.products.brand)>,
 <Feature: customers.COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: customers.COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: customers.MODE(transactions.product_id)>]
```

this creates features using the `count` and `mode` primitives, but ignores the device variable in the sessions entity. if we want to include the device variable in its original state we can add it back in like this

```
feature_defs += [ft.Feature(es["sessions"]["device"])]
```

Now, we can calculate the feature matrix. `device` is now at the end

```
fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features=feature_defs, entityset=es)
fm

            customer_id  COUNT(transactions)  MODE(transactions.product_id) customers.zip_code   ...    customers.COUNT(sessions)  customers.COUNT(transactions)  customers.MODE(transactions.product_id)   device
session_id                                                                                       ...                                                                                                              
1                     2                   16                              3              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4  desktop
2                     5                   10                              5              60091   ...                            6                             79                                        5   mobile
3                     4                   15                              1              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2   mobile
4                     1                   25                              5              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4   mobile
5                     4                   11                              5              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2   mobile
6                     1                   15                              4              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4   tablet
7                     3                   15                              1              13244   ...                            6                             93                                        1   tablet
8                     4                   18                              1              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2   tablet
9                     1                   15                              1              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4  desktop
10                    2                   15                              2              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4   tablet
11                    4                   15                              3              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2   mobile
12                    4                   10                              4              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2  desktop
13                    4                   12                              2              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2   mobile
14                    1                   12                              4              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4   tablet
15                    2                    8                              2              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4  desktop
16                    2                   10                              4              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4  desktop
17                    2                   13                              1              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4   tablet
18                    1                   12                              2              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4  desktop
19                    3                   17                              1              13244   ...                            6                             93                                        1  desktop
20                    5                   15                              1              60091   ...                            6                             79                                        5  desktop
21                    4                   18                              5              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2  desktop
22                    4                   10                              2              60091   ...                            8                            109                                        2  desktop
23                    3                   11                              3              13244   ...                            6                             93                                        1  desktop
24                    5                   14                              4              60091   ...                            6                             79                                        5   tablet
25                    3                   16                              1              13244   ...                            6                             93                                        1  desktop
26                    1                   16                              1              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4   tablet
27                    1                   15                              5              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4   mobile
28                    5                   18                              2              60091   ...                            6                             79                                        5   mobile
29                    1                   16                              4              60091   ...                            8                            126                                        4   mobile
30                    5                   14                              3              60091   ...                            6                             79                                        5  desktop
31                    2                   18                              3              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4   mobile
32                    5                    8                              3              60091   ...                            6                             79                                        5   mobile
33                    2                   13                              3              13244   ...                            7                             93                                        4   mobile
34                    3                   18                              4              13244   ...                            6                             93                                        1  desktop
35                    3                   16                              5              13244   ...                            6                             93                                        1   mobile
```

As a sanity check, this is what the output is if we don't use `ignore_variables`

```
feature_defs = ft.dfs(target_entity="sessions",
                      entityset=es, 
                      agg_primitives=["count", "mode"],
                      trans_primitives=[],
                      features_only=True)
```

you can see the feature `<Feature: customers.MODE(sessions.device)>` gets created now

```
[<Feature: customer_id>,
 <Feature: device>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: MODE(transactions.product_id)>,
 <Feature: customers.zip_code>,
 <Feature: MODE(transactions.products.brand)>,
 <Feature: customers.COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: customers.MODE(sessions.device)>,
 <Feature: customers.COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: customers.MODE(transactions.product_id)>]
```